# Query Matching Column Elements Against Multiple Filters

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am currently writing a script to filter objects matching specified taxonomies. Each object is represented in an SQL table by an object_id. The objects each possess a series of attributes (1,2,3, etc), which are further subdivided into terms (1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 2c, etc). The terms are represented by a term_taxonomy_id. See the example table below:

| object_id | term_taxonomy_id | term_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 14 | 0 |
| 100 | 16 | 0 |
| 100 | 17 | 0 |
| 101 | 14 | 0 |
| 101 | 20 | 0 |
| 102 | 17 | 0 |

I want a query to match each unique object_id against a list of term_taxonomy_id's. For example, if a user has selected taxonomies 14, 16, and 17 as filters, the query I'm looking for would output '100' from the example table.

I know how to query each individual term_taxonomy_id for matches. For instance, querying object_id's with term_taxonomy_id's matching 14 would output '100' and '101.' Currently, I'm running a query like this for each term_taxonomy_id, putting the results in arrays, then comparing the arrays in PHP to get objects matching all selected taxonomies. It works, but it feels clunky.

This is why I'm looking for a way to filter for multiple taxonomy ID's in one query. Instead of calling multiple queries (One per taxonomy), then performing operations on the resulting arrays, I could just make one clean database call. This added efficiency will be very important for the project I'm working on, as we may have dozens of taxonomies with thousands of potential matches in the future.

Comment: In your circumstance, are you unable to use the wp_query class, or are you unfamiliar with the way to build queries the WordPress way?

Comment: Also, please post the code you are using to query an individual term_taxonomy_id.

Comment: I did some digging, and found an example of WP_Tax_Query being used for multi-taxonomy queries using relations. That sufficiently answers my question, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I am still quite new to database operations.

Comment: I had previously been using a built-in WordPress function:
get_objects_in_term(),
but it was matching multiple terms by OR instead of AND, so I thought I'd need a custom SQL query.

Comment: Excellent!  Are you sure you are achieving AND matching with your query?  That can be tricky sometimes.